# Custom tags in Spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I've got custom tag. It works properly, but not at all. My `jsp` looks like:

```
<test:myTag>${headHunter.salary}</test:myTag>
```

Where `${headHunter.salary}` is some value. And tag:

```
public int doAfterBody() throws JspException {
    String content = bodyContent.getString();
    try {
        JspWriter out = bodyContent.getEnclosingWriter();
        out.print(content);         
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

So if `${headHunter.salary}` equals `10`, tag must return the same value. But it returs only `"${headHunter.salary}"` as string. Whats wrong?

**UPD**

taglib.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <shortname></shortname>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <tag>
        <name>myTag</name>
        <tagclass>net.babobka.blog.tags.CurrencyTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>tagDependent</bodycontent>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Comment: Do you have EL enabled?

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. What is EL?

Comment: Oh, do you mean SpEL?

Comment: [Expression Language (EL)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) is what your `${headHunter.salary}` expression is. It needs to be enabled if you're going to use it.

Comment: I think yes. It's enabled. It works without tags. `${headHunter.salary}` - ok, value is on the page, `<test:myTag>${headHunter.salary}</test:myTag>` - nope.

Comment: Please show us your tag declaration. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
<bodycontent>tagDependent</bodycontent>
```

It should default the `scriptless`. [It seems `tagDependent` prevents EL from being resolved](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).

Comment: @Tony Note that there might be other consequences. Go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) for configuring custom tags.